# JQuery replace not working with JW Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jwplayer

I may be going about this in completely the wrong way, but I'm pretty new to JavaScript and this was the easiest way I could figure out to do it. I'm trying to have a thumbnail at the top of my page be replaced by a JW Player video when a button is clicked. Here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="series_graphic"></div>
<button class="button-watch1">Watch now</button>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $( ".button-watch1" ).click(function() {
    $( ".series_graphic" ).replaceWith( '<div id="player-1">Loading</div>');
 });


    jwplayer("player-1").setup({
        file: "",
        height: 360,
        image: "",
        width: 640
    });
```

I can get it to work just fine if I remove the .click function, but as soon as I add it, all that it will show is the "Loading" text and nothing else. I've done quite a bit of troubleshooting/searching and can't seem to figure it out. I've also tried an onclick on the button and it returned the same results.

Sorry if this is a super dumb/simple question. I really appreciate any help as I've spent a long time trying to figure it out!

Comment: Do you have a demo of where you tries this?

Comment: Yes, it's [here](http://andrewanguiano.com/ee//lbc/series/pray-like-jesus). It's still very much in progress ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your call to `jwplayer` inside the `click` handler.

```
$( ".button-watch1" ).click(function() {
    $( ".series_graphic" ).replaceWith('<div id="player-1">Loading</div>');
    jwplayer("player-1").setup({
        file: "",
        height: 360,
        image: "",
        width: 640
    });
 });
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks a million! It was definitely driving me crazy.